# ImportError, but the module contains __init__.py, and I believe I've added it to sys.path

Tags: python, selenium, importerror

I am working on a web crawler using Scrapy, and have been trying to use selenium in my code, but I continue to get an ImportError when I declare "from selenium import webdriver" or even just "import selenium".

The selenium directory exists in my site-packages folder, and I also followed some advice from another thread and tried creating a .pth file in my site-packages folder that contained the address of the selenium directory, but I am still getting this error. I also tried "pip install selenium" and that changed nothing.

If anyone could help with this, it would be much appreciated. I'm sure it's a simple fix, but it's really holding up my progress on my project.

Comment: Could you post the entire output from the ImportError?  It can be helpful sometimes.

Comment: If you're using python3 try using `pip3 install selenium`

Comment: Did you add the directory containing the `__init__.py` file to the path? If so, that's the problem. The `__init__.py` file is not the module. The directory it's in is the module. The path lists directories containing modules, not modules. So the directory that *contains* the directory that contains `__init__.py` needs to be in the path.